# Unable to transfer files with asmack

Tags: android, xmpp, file-transfer, smack, asmack

I have created a chat application and i am using asmack lib.
I'm trying to transfer a file between two clients (Android app) on the same XMPP server, but I get a weird error.

When I try to send a file, the outgoing file transfer begins, and the destination client receives the request, but the source client cannot go further in the transfer negotiation . I am always stuck in 'Negotiating Transfer'...

Only managed to transfer files successfully, by sending a file from the mobile application to a desktop application (eg. Spark IM Client).

Any idea what is causing this?

Sending file:

```
OutgoingFileTransfer lTransfer = mFileTransferManager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(mJid+"/"+resource);
// Send the file
try {
    lTransfer.sendFile(new File(filePath),mMessage);
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
    Log.e(TAG,"Error sending file");
}

while(!lTransfer.isDone()){
    if(lTransfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.error)) {
        Log.e(TAG,"ERROR!!! " + lTransfer.getError());
        } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Status:"+lTransfer.getStatus().toString());
        Log.i(TAG, "Progress:"+String.valueOf(lTransfer.getProgress()));
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException ignored) { }
}

if(lTransfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.refused)
|| lTransfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.error)
|| lTransfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.cancelled)){
    Log.e(TAG,"refused cancelled error " + lTransfer.getError());
    return false;
    } else {
    Log.i(TAG,"Sucesss");
    return true;
}
```

Receiving file:

```
mFileTransferManager.addFileTransferListener(new FileTransferListener() {
    public void fileTransferRequest(FileTransferRequest request) {
        String path = "/sdcard/"+ request.getFileName();
        IncomingFileTransfer lTransfer = fileTransferRequest.accept();
        lTransfer.recieveFile(new File(path));
        double percents = 0.0;
        while (!lTransfer.isDone()) {
            if (lTransfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.in_progress)) {
                percents = ((int) (lTransfer.getProgress() * 10000)) / 100.0;
                Log.d(TAG, "File transfer: " + newFile.getAbsolutePath() + " - " + percents + "%");
                } else if (lTransfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.error)) {
                Log.e(TAG, "ERROR in transfer");
                return;
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        if (lTransfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.complete)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "File transfert: " + newFile.getAbsolutePath() + " - 100%");
            } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "ERROR in transfer");
        }
    });
```

ProviderManager configure

```
ProviderManager pm = ProviderManager.getInstance();
 //  Private Data Storage
        pm.addIQProvider("query","jabber:iq:private", new PrivateDataManager.PrivateDataIQProvider());
        //  Time
        try {
            pm.addIQProvider("query","jabber:iq:time", Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Time"));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            QuickLogger.w("Can't load class for org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Time");
        }

        //  XHTML
        pm.addExtensionProvider("html","http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im", new XHTMLExtensionProvider());

        //  Roster Exchange
        pm.addExtensionProvider("x","jabber:x:roster", new RosterExchangeProvider());
        //  Message Events
        pm.addExtensionProvider("x","jabber:x:event", new MessageEventProvider());
        //  Chat State
        pm.addExtensionProvider("active","http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
        pm.addExtensionProvider("composing","http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
        pm.addExtensionProvider("paused","http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
        pm.addExtensionProvider("inactive","http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
        pm.addExtensionProvider("gone","http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());

        //   FileTransfer
        pm.addIQProvider("si","http://jabber.org/protocol/si", new StreamInitiationProvider());
        pm.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams", new BytestreamsProvider());
        pm.addIQProvider("open","http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new OpenIQProvider());
        pm.addIQProvider("close","http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new CloseIQProvider());
        pm.addExtensionProvider("data","http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new DataPacketProvider());

        //  Group Chat Invitations
        pm.addExtensionProvider("x","jabber:x:conference", new GroupChatInvitation.Provider());
        //  Service Discovery # Items
        pm.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items", new DiscoverItemsProvider());
        //  Service Discovery # Info
        pm.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info", new DiscoverInfoProvider());
        //  Data Forms
        pm.addExtensionProvider("x","jabber:x:data", new DataFormProvider());
        //  MUC User
        pm.addExtensionProvider("x","http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user", new MUCUserProvider());
        //  MUC Admin
        pm.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin", new MUCAdminProvider());
        //  MUC Owner
        pm.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#owner", new MUCOwnerProvider());
        //  Delayed Delivery
        pm.addExtensionProvider("x","jabber:x:delay", new DelayInformationProvider());
        //  Version
        try {
            pm.addIQProvider("query","jabber:iq:version", Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Version"));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            QuickLogger.w("Can't load class for org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Version");
        }
        //  VCard
        pm.addIQProvider("vCard","vcard-temp", new VCardProvider());
        //  Offline Message Requests
        pm.addIQProvider("offline","http://jabber.org/protocol/offline", new OfflineMessageRequest.Provider());
        //  Offline Message Indicator
        pm.addExtensionProvider("offline","http://jabber.org/protocol/offline", new OfflineMessageInfo.Provider());
        //  Last Activity
        pm.addIQProvider("query","jabber:iq:last", new LastActivity.Provider());
        //  User Search
        pm.addIQProvider("query","jabber:iq:search", new UserSearch.Provider());
        //  SharedGroupsInfo
        pm.addIQProvider("sharedgroup","http://www.jivesoftware.org/protocol/sharedgroup", new SharedGroupsInfo.Provider());
        //  JEP-33: Extended Stanza Addressing
        pm.addExtensionProvider("addresses","http://jabber.org/protocol/address", new MultipleAddressesProvider());
```

Comment: I suggest you have a look at https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack/wiki/aSmack-XMPP-File-Transfer

Comment: already done that. i have also configured `ProviderManager` (code added)

Comment: Then where is the trace of the involved XMPP stanzas?

Comment: It doesn't look like that this capture is complete.

Comment: trace update: https://gist.github.com/filipebatista/2eb646d9ed09ed057c37

Comment: I know that this is possible not the response you hoped for, but the stanzas end with negotiating a bytestream and then an ibb transfer. It still looks like the actual error stanza is missing. I recommend having a look at the specs to find out how a XMPP filetransfer usually should look like on protocol level. I am sure it will give you a hint about what's going wrong.

Comment: i have also noticed that in the app that is receiving the file the `IncomingFileTransfer.getException()` returns the following: `Error in execution: 
  -- caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: File transfer negotiation failed.: `